# File chooser opens 'Recent' folder instead of inserted path

Tags: android, android-intent, filepicker

I'm trying to open a specific folder using intent, but the device's recent folder open instead.

Code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(filepath);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,uri);
intent.setDataAndType(uri,"text/plain");
StartActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not take a `Uri`, so yours is ignored.

[With `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=en#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT), you can use `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` to provide some document tree (e.g., from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`) that should be used as the initial location.

Comment: Changed to ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, but it just open the last folder that was chosen before.

Comment: I can't seem to find where to use EXTRA_INITIAL_URI